# How to remove this white HTML space below footer?

Tags: html, css, sass

I've created a responsive webpage and everything is working fine. I mean the layout for mobile like smartphones and tablets is ok. If I switch to desktop it looks good too except for the footer and that's because there is an empty white space at the end of the webpage if I click on inspect the browser focus the HTML tag.

[image]

One thing you have to notice is that the height of this empty space depends on the width of the viewport. Also I'm using sass. I can't share all the code here because it's divided across too many files. If you want to see all the code go here: https://github.com/justanindieguy/podcast-landing-page

And also you can see the webpage in this github personal page: https://justanindieguy.github.io/podcast-landing-page/

Thanks a lot for all your answers. This is driving me nuts, I can't find the solution.

Comment: the footer padding in `keyframes.scss` line 7, seems to be the problem, try doing an inspect element on the `footer` and removing the `padding: 1% 5%;` property and see for yourself

Comment: I see that the blank inexplicable gap is caused by the `<section id='news'>` transformation...removing the transformation removes the gap, so i think your solution lies there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the given solutions from others to make sure none already did the trick on your page, but no success.

I then found the reason you're getting the issue. It's related to the :before of the news section, it's overflowing from the element.

Try adding this CSS :

```
#news {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Now the news section crops the :before element relative to its own dimensions. 
I noticed you achieved the layout with skew, but I recommend you to look into clip path generators and create this shape that way.

Comment: Great to hear. You can keep the episodes section as it doesn't have any conflicts, but using clip path would lower the amount of html & css by a very small amount.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to top of your CSS file

```
* {
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
}
```